# Mergesort an array of numbers

Tags: java

I have created a program to Mergesort a short string of elements entered in by the user. I want to instead fill the beggining array with randomly generated numbers. Is this possible by using the math.random? Also how would I generate numbers in a given range? (ie. 5-50 or 0-1). Thanks for the help I have included my code below.

```
public class MergeSort 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        //{
        //  String[i] = Math.random();
        //}
        //Unsorted array
        Integer[] a = { 2, 6, 3, 5, 1, 4, 10};

        //Call merge sort
        mergeSort(a);

        //Check the output which is sorted array
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }

    public static Comparable[] mergeSort(Comparable[] list) 
    {
        //If list is empty; no need to do anything
        if (list.length <= 1) {
            return list;
        }

        //Split the array in half in two parts
        Comparable[] first = new Comparable[list.length / 2];
        Comparable[] second = new Comparable[list.length - first.length];
        System.arraycopy(list, 0, first, 0, first.length);
        System.arraycopy(list, first.length, second, 0, second.length);

        //Sort each half recursively
        mergeSort(first);
        mergeSort(second);

        //Merge both halves together, overwriting to original array
        merge(first, second, list);
        return list;
    }


    private static void merge(Comparable[] first, Comparable[] second, Comparable[] result) 
    {
        //Index Position in first array - starting with first element
        int iFirst = 0;

        //Index Position in second array - starting with first element
        int iSecond = 0;

        //Index Position in merged array - starting with first position
        int iMerged = 0;

        //Compare elements at iFirst and iSecond, 
        //and move smaller element at iMerged
        while (iFirst < first.length && iSecond < second.length) 
        {
            if (first[iFirst].compareTo(second[iSecond]) < 0) 
            {
                result[iMerged] = first[iFirst];
                iFirst++;
            } 
            else
            {
                result[iMerged] = second[iSecond];
                iSecond++;
            }
            iMerged++;
        }
        //copy remaining elements from both halves - each half will have already sorted elements
        System.arraycopy(first, iFirst, result, iMerged, first.length - iFirst);
        System.arraycopy(second, iSecond, result, iMerged, second.length - iSecond);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and avoid posting "blabber". Ask a single, coherent, specific question.

Comment: instead of using coder input values i want a list of randomly generated number where i can control how many and what range. @Amit. Im assuming math.random would help in this case.

Comment: @Tomlangdorr That's much better. You should edit your question to just ask that. (Delete everything that has to do with "merge sort," since that's unrelated to your question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to construct an array full of random integers. (In this case, they're random integers greater than or equal to 0 and less than 100.)

```
int[] a = new int[10];

Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a[i] = rand.nextInt(100);
}
```

If you wanted to produce numbers between 5 (inclusive) and 50 (exclusive), you could use `rand.nextInt(45) + 5`.

To generalize:

```
rand.nextInt(max-min) + min
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. How would I implement this into my code?

Comment: @Tomlangdorr I'm not sure how to answer that. Copy/paste it into your code, I guess?

Comment: how would i implement this for a double value and replace this string with my current string?

Comment: To get doubles: `rand.nextDouble() * (max-min) + min`

Comment: I have no idea what "replace this string with my current string" means.

Comment: I meant my unsorted array with the new randomly generated one. Thanks for the help. I believe i have figured out my solution.